# Yocto project System manger as "Init.d"

Tags: embedded, stm32, yocto

I have developed an yocto image based on openstlinux distribution. Current distribution is using "systemd" as system manager. But I have a requirement to use the system manager as "init.d". I searched in Google to find the correct way to set the system manager as "init.d", but I can only find information for the "systemd". Can anyone tell me, how to set the system manager as "init.d"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like a backwards requirement - init.d stuff has been obsolete for quite a while. You could use an older Yocto build, but you'd get an old kernel and and all the old programs with all the old bugs and vulnerabilities. I don't know of a modern Linux system (let alone Yocto) that use that. Why is there a requirement for it? Because there is an init.d script for some old program? That would take an hour to change to use systemd.

Comment: Did you check out yocto documentation here? https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/init-manager.html#selecting-an-initialization-manager

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I just have a little bit modification for the requirement. The main system manager will be "systemd", but I also need to have a init.d, so that they can run their old init.d script in the system.  Can I install systemd and init.d at the same time, because in beaglebone-black If I install systemd, then I can not find init.d, though I installed both of them in my local.conf. 

Do you have any idea how to install the at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem.

The modified idea was to run old init.d script in the current systemd manager. To do that I used "systemctl status myjob.service" or "systemctl enable myjob.service". Here I faced that in systemd "systemd-sysv-install" folder is missing, and without that I can not run my old script.

Then I created a bbappend file to install that folder in the systemd.

Now the final problem was old init.d scripts weren't starting at the bootup. I had to manually enable those script by giving command "systemd enable myjob.service". In here my recipe was missing linking between the files and rc1,....,rc5.

After linking those files, I was able to run my old script at the bootup.

Following link was helpful for this problem:
[Solution for this problem](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Cookbook:Appliance:Startup_Scripts)

Thanks everyone for your support.